# How can I undo a sha change from git rebase interactive?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I did an interactive rebase with more commits than I needed to change. I was surprised that the shas of the unnessisary changes were updated. Unfortunately I only realised this happened after I force pushed my updates.

**What I did**

Starting point

```
X - Y \
A - B - C  *master (C is a merge commit)
         \
          - D - E *feature-branch
```

- ran `git rebase -i head~3`
- squashed `D` and `E` (we'll call this
  `D1`)
- changed the commit message of the new `D1` commit
- Left `A`, `B`, and `C` as `pick` and didn't make any changes

My expectation was that everything would look like this:

```
X - Y \
A - B - C  *master
         \
          - D1 *feature-branch
```

- force pushed my branch

When I went to my PR, things actually looked like this:

```
X - Y \
A - B - C  *master
         \
          - A1 - B1 - C1 - D1 *feature-branch
```

Where `A1`, `B1`, and `C1` had the same commit messages and changes as `A`, `B`, and `C`, but with different shas.

**Questions**

- How can I remove `A1`, `B1`, and `C1` from my PR without impacting master's `A`, `B`, and `C`?
- What's going on with `rebase -i`? Why did including `A`, `B`, and `C` in my rebase command make any changes since I just left them as `pick`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way if you just want to delete A1/B1/C1 is to do a `git rebase -i C`. Mark A1 as 'reword', and B1 through D1 as 'fixup'. Edit the commit message for A1 to be what you want as the final message.

Now, as to what went wrong: `C` is a merge commit.

That means your history graph probably actually looked like this:

```
   A - B - C  *master
          / \
...-X-Y-Z    - D - E *feature-branch
```

When you said `HEAD~5`, that took the **first parent** of HEAD five times. Let's say the first parent of `C` is `Z` instead of `B`. That means you're rebasing onto commit `X`, and one of the commits you're planting there is `A`. The new `A` gets a new commit hash because its ancestry (and possibly its content) changed.

You might not have noticed `Y` and `Z` showing up in the rebase-interactive editor window and just left them as `pick`.

Basically, the `rebase` takes your nonlinear history and squishes it into being a line. I can't say I recommend using a rebase across a merge commit.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reflog reminder - I updated my question to include the full history from my reflog. Perhaps that makes it clearer what happened?

Comment: @LucyBain Thank you for mentioning that `C` is a merge. That is the source of your issue. Rebase linearly replays commits; if you include a merge commit in the scope of the rebase, the results are not what you might expect. That's why my answer included "with history that looks like your graph".

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation! I'm sorry I didn't mention it in the original question then, I didn't think it would make such a difference :(

Answer (score -1):

If you run `git revert` for A1 - B1 - C1 , your new branch will effectively be the one that you desire. And this operation is safer

Comment: I believe this will make new commits on my branch for the three reverts (`A1'`, `B1'`, and `C1'`) that would then be in my PR to merge back, effectively undoing the code in `A`, `B`, and `C` on master.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I will suggest to do it this way as it does not break anything for others who pull your branch. Rebasing to remove pushed changes is something I would be against as it also spoils history of other users.